# Open git bash shell window, execute command and remain after term signal

Tags: windows, git, bash, shell, maven

I have a batch file that sets up my environment by opening a number of "git bash" shell windows. This works perfectly apart from one annoying feature where if you press Ctrl C (or send any other Term signal) the whole bash window will close.

I want the window to behave as if it has been opened normally and so when it receives a term signal it goes back to the bash prompt.

Here is the current contents of my setup.bat file:

```
C:
cd \project\
start "" "%SYSTEMDRIVE%\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i -l -c "source ali.sh && mvn spring-boot:run"
cd \project2\
start "" "%SYSTEMDRIVE%\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login
```

Note that the first start command runs maven and when i want to restart the command (press Ctrl+C) it closes the whole window.
The second start command creates a new bash window in that directory which works like a normal bash window even with Ctrl+C, BUT I want it to have run a command at the start.

Is this possible?
Many thanks for all your help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this might work for you:

```
C:
cd \project\
start "" "%SYSTEMDRIVE%\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i -l -c "sh -c 'source ali.sh && mvn spring-boot:run; exec sh'"
```

The trick is wrapping the command in:

```
sh -c '...; exec sh'
```

Where `sh` is your shell, might be `bash`.

You might actually to able to just suffix each command with: `exec sh`, eg:

```
start "" "%SYSTEMDRIVE%\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i -l -c "source ali.sh && mvn spring-boot:run; exec sh"
```