# bat file to issue a git pull command and leave the git bash window open

Tags: git, batch-file, git-bash

I have a .bat file that will access a git-hub repository and then issue the "git pull" command.  I would like for the Git Bash window to stay open once the "git pull" is complete.    Any suggestions?   The .bat code that I'm using is below.

```
cd Class/UKED201801FSF2-Class-Repository-FSF

c:\Users\johnc\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\git-bash.exe -c 'git pull'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch files : How to leave the console window open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13746177/batch-files-how-to-leave-the-console-window-open)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your .bat should be:

```
cd Class/UKED201801FSF2-Class-Repository-FSF
c:\Users\johnc\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\git-bash.exe -c 'git pull; exec sh'
```

Answer (score 3):

As in "[Open git bash shell window, execute command and remain after term signal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37775038/6309)", see if you can add a shell command after your (here `git pull`) original command

```
git-bash -c '...; exec bash'
```